# How do I add a Form Load event using the form designer in C# 2015? (like double clicking)?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am new to C# in Visual Studio 2015. I just realized that the old classical way of adding event handlers by double-clicking on the item no longer works for some items like the form (or the Window).

After some Google searches I still can't figure out a way to add the Load event of the form using the designer.

Do I have to manually write code for that unlike in Visual Basic in Visual Studio 2005?

Comment: Not happening here....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the Load event of a Control from its properties window [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sl2R8.png). You create the

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // my code
}
```

event in your form class, and fill in its name (Form1_Load) where the arrow points in the picture.

Doing it manually would be something like:

```
Form1.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
```

considering that you created the Form1_Load event.

But on top of all that, double clicking *should* work.

Comment: exactly what I needed

Answer (score 0):

You may have an issue with your instillation. However, select the form and go to the actions window and select load. This should give the desired result