# How to execute code as soon as the form loads?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm a student and haven't coded for long at all and as such don't know many of the features that are usable.

Right now I'm facing an issue where I have my first form summon another form that I then want to rapidly change colors as soon as it opens.

I had already made a form that rapidly changes color as soon as I press a button but here I want it to start as soon as it appears.

I understand that this question might have been asked before but I couldn't really find an answer that worked. Some people were saying stuff about using "OnLoad" or "Application.run" but I can't seem to get those things to come up when I type them into Microsoft visual studio.

Here is the code of the initial form:

```
    private void btnkör_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.Show();
    }
```

And here is the code of the second form that is summoned by the first:

```
  private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Visible = true;

        Timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {         
        Random Generator = new Random();

        BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, Generator.Next(1, 256), Generator.Next(1, 256), Generator.Next(1, 256));
    }
```

FYI the second form is a completely empty square form while the first is a very small window taken up entirely by the "kör" button (means "run" in Swedish)

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37377122/how-do-i-add-a-form-load-event-using-the-form-designer-in-c-sharp-2015-like-do) help? Check out [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218732/how-do-i-execute-code-after-a-form-has-loaded) too.

Comment: a) you should not create multiple Random objects let alone in quck succession. b) you may need to give the ui time to refresh itself. adding a Refresh() in the Tick might help. c) did you set the Timer.Interval?

Comment: You can simply call Timer_Tick directly.  It is a lot prettier when you move that code into another method so you don't have to fret over the arguments that Timer_Tick needs.  Even though (this, EventArgs.Empty) works just fine.  Fix the bug while you're at it, only allocate Random once by making it a member of the class.

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what doesn't work? What happens and what you expect instead? Typically you would do all initialization in the form constructor, say setting initial background color there. I recall what I had to use [Shown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.shown?view=netframework-4.7.2) event in some cases (can't give an example now why), which is basically what you ask for, it's the very first event after form is displayed.

Comment: You call: 'f2.Show();' Then you don't need: 'this.Visible = true;' in form load event.

Comment: Btw.: this is a good time to start coding in english only. If you have to explain that `kör` means `run`, you might see that it would be much better to call it `run` in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you need a timer?
Is it important that user notices such color change?
Otherwise, why would you not just set that color before showing the form? No timers involved, event handlers etc. With this approach, you're in full control.

```
private void btnkör_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    f2.BackColor = Color.OrangeRed;
    f2.Show();
}
```

This way, your back color will be set, after form is created/initialized and before it is shown. It will be displayed as 'OrangeRed' and user will not notice such change.

Of course, put your code in place that randomly generates color. Bear in mind second comment related to the 'Random' object.

In case you do not need random color, but some static, you could set BackColor property directly on the form (in design mode) and would not need this piece of code.

Comment: I think  BackColor property of Form2 should be public to access it from Form 1. Isn't it? Otherwise this is the perfect answer

Comment: OP seems to want to "rapidly change" the color of `Form2`, as in "and keep changing it over and over", not "only once and then stay at that one color". -- basically: a seizure generator. ^_^